# Empty LEGO boxes: are they worth anything?

Tags: shopping

I have 4 garbage bags full of empty LEGO boxes, at least 20+ years old. Are they worth anything? Is there somewhere to post them for sale?

Comment: it might depdend on many things. I would surf ebay or similar sites to check if these items are traded there. May not be interesting to most people, but if you happend to find the right collector they might be interested on such items.

Comment: i mean, if someone has the set and they dont have the box, buying a box for the set might get the person more money when selling their set.

Comment: @eva that's true, that's also why sometimes "pat pending" bricks can be sold for a *little bit* more for sets that are old

Comment: experience shows when selling old sets incl. the box on ebay or bricklink the price will be higher. same goes for me when i am buying, the box to me is absolutely valuable

Answer (score 6):

On Bricklink.com vendors sell original boxes. You can see a listing of what's available [here](https://www.bricklink.com/browseTree.asp?itemType=O). For example, the [King's Mountain Fortress from 1990 is offered for sale for about $65 USD](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?O=6081-1#T=S&O=%7B%7D). (I have the front and back flaps of that box, I wonder if I could list just those.)

Bricklink shows a price guide for products which have been sold recently; Some of the boxes show sales and some of them don't.  Whether you can get any specific price for a box will depend greatly on the condition of the box, how you manage your bricklink reputation, and how patient you are.